# Fail to use 'powershell' through telnet connection using pexpect (python)

Tags: python, powershell, telnet

Trying to send 'powershell' command through telnet (from linux to windows) and fail on Timeout.
other commands i send through telnet, such as 'dir' command are ok.

this is part of the code i'm using:

```
p = host.pobject()
    p.cmd = cmd
    child = self.connection or self.OpenTelnetConnection()
    t = stopwatch.Timer()
    try:
        child.sendline('{0}\r'.format(cmd))
        child.expect(self.prompt, timeout=timeout)
        # output = child.before
        output = child.after
        if stdout:
            sys.stdout.write(child.after)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        child.sendline('echo %errorlevel%\r')
        child.expect(self.prompt)
        p.rc = int(child.after.split("\r\n")[1])
        p.runtime = t.stop()
        if p.rc:
            p.stderr = output.split("\r\n")[1:-1]
        else:
            p.stdout = output.split("\r\n")[1:-1]
        return p
    except Exception, e:
        self.report.Error("Failed to run command {0}. {1}".format(cmd, e),
                          exception=["TestFailure"], testName="WindowsHost")
```

Comment: It's not fare to downgrade a question without appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to send the powershell command as 1st argument.
for example if i want to send 'host' command to the powershell i'll send:
'powershell host'